# Javascript - move/drag icons to table

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to like 10x10 table where I can drag images to each another.

Does anybody have an idea how this can be accomplished using JavaScript? I have already tried something with Dragula but it didn't work well.

This is what I want to work in real time:

[image]

Comment: what you have tried

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

You can add the

```
draggable="true"
```

attribute to the html elements.
If that doesn't help then try checking out [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp).
You can also check out [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drop)
Hope this helps.